# Laravel hasManyThrough not works

Tags: php, laravel, postgresql

My code:

```
    public function users()
    {
        return $this->hasManyThrough(
            'App\Models\User',
            'App\Models\UserGroupDue',
            'user_id',
            'id',
            'name',
            'group_name'
        );
    }
```

The error:
[image]

My users table:

[image]

My users groups due table:

[image]

My groups table:

[image]

Comment: your `groups` table is not linked with either `users groups` or `users` table, so it's not `hasManyThrough`.

Comment: have a read the doc, https://laravel.com/docs/7.x/eloquent-relationships#has-many-through, make sure you understand how it works.

Comment: if you add an integer ID to the groups table (instead of a string "name") you can put in place a `BelongsToMany` between user and group.

Comment: I resolved adding " public $keyType = 'string'; " in Group model

Comment: id should be integer

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem is in the user function

try this

```
public function users()
{
    return $this->hasManyThrough(
        'App\Models\User',
        'App\Models\UserGroupDue',
        'user_id',
        'group_name'
        'id',
        'name',
    );
}
```